# Why does ec2 monitoring show 100% cpu and top only 20%?

Tags: amazon-ec2, top

I am running an python script on an ec2 instance that inserts rows in an database on another instance. In ec2's monitoring I saw a 100% cpu utilization, whereas top only shows 20% for the python process. What is missing from top? Network overhead?

Comment: What about all the *other* processes?

Comment: At around 0% utilization

Comment: I am also in dillima, I send my TOP command reprot to the client  :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The data exposed by `top` is often insufficient or misleading in virtualized environments like [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) and the reported percentage depends on your instance type and the under­ly­ing proces­sor core utilization (which usually doesn't match the virtualized hardware you are presented with from the hypervisor), amongst other things - what you are seeing is most likely caused by respective *CPU steal time* as exposed in most related Unix/Linux monitoring tools nowadays - see e.g. columns %steal or st in `sar` or `top`:

> **st -- Steal Time**
> The amount of CPU 'stolen' from this virtual machine
> by the hypervisor for other tasks (such as running another virtual
> machine).

The blog post [EC2 monitoring: the case of stolen CPU](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202114048/https://axibase.com/news/ec2-monitoring-the-case-of-stolen-cpu/) provides a nice exploration and illustration of this topic:

> When the top com­mand dis­plays 40% CPU busy but Cloud­Watch says the
> server is maxed out at 100% — which side do you take? The answer is
> sim­ple (Cloud­Watch is cor­rect, top is not) [...]

Please note that this hypervisor metric seems to be (easily) accessible on Unix/Linux systems only, but doesn't seem to be observable on Windows (yet), see my question [Is there a Windows equivalent of Unix 'CPU steal time'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/392216/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-unix-cpu-steal-time) for more regarding this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the blogpost. That really makes it clear. It is really good to know this since I am about to roll out Ganglia, and it would be a shame to measure the wrong metrics. Measure %idletime!

Comment: In my case, cloudwatch is also reporting 3mb/s network usage, but when I look on my server (with iftop, iptraf, netstat, etc) I see that the only thing with a network connection is my ssh into the server. Which I really doubt is using 3mb/s...

Answer (score -2):

Amazon probably check load and no percentage usage from TOP.
If you have two processes on cpu, they can be utilized on 20% but you can have load 2.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with load 2...

Comment: You can have system load at 2. Two processes on CPU but with low utilization.